# Copy the layer_styles table from one database to another?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, style, table, copy

I am trying to copy the layer_styles table to another database. A quick and painless process is preferred, to make the movement of the layer_styles tables easy to repeat in the future.

I have tried two methods so far: 
1. pg_dump and psql
2. Creating a dblink

Neither seem to work. The culprit seems to be the xml type in the layer_styles table.

1. I've had success using pg-dump and restore with other tables, however not the layer_styles table. Using pg_restore returns the following error:

> ```
>    ERROR:  invalid XML content
>     DETAIL:  line 1: StartTag: invalid element name
>     <!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
>      ^
>     CONTEXT:  COPY layer_styles, line 1, column styleqml: "<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
>     <qgis simplifyLocal="1" maxScale="0" minS..."
>      setval
> ```

The end result is an empty layer_styles table in the target database.

2. After creating the dblink, I run the following code:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE layer_styles
> AS
> SELECT
> from dblink('host=localhost
>               user=postgres
>               password=postgres
>               dbname=database3',
>               'select *
>               from layer_styles') AS linktable(
>         a integer,
>         b varchar,
>         c varchar,
>         d varchar,
>         e text,
>         f xml,
>         g xml,
>         h boolean,
>         i text,
>         j varchar,
>         k xml,
>         l timestamp);
> ```

This returns the following error:

```
>  ERROR:  invalid XML content
>     DETAIL:  line 1: StartTag: invalid element name
>     <!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
>      ^
```

I have had previous success with the dblink when using different tables without an XML type.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via DB-manager:

- you can load the table into QGIS.
- Then connect to another database
- import the layer_styles-table

Or you can create an empty table in the target_database:

```
CREATE TABLE public.layer_styles
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('layer_styles_id_seq'::regclass),
    f_table_catalog character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    f_table_schema character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    f_table_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    f_geometry_column character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    stylename character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    styleqml xml,
    stylesld xml,
    useasdefault boolean,
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    owner character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    ui xml,
    update_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT layer_styles_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Then load the content into it with DB-manager

Comment: I am not sure I have done exactly what you've stated. Please instruct if I haven't.

In DB Manager, in source database, I exported layer_styles and saved in documents.

In DB Manager, in target database, I imported the same file. 

This returns error message:
"
Error 6
Feature write errors:
Creation error for features from #0 to #0. Provider errors was: 
PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)

Only 0 of 10 features written."


Do you know how I should proceed? The resulting layer_styles table in the target database is empty.

Comment: you should not export the table, just load it in QGIS.  Then import it in the target database, using DB-manager.  When retrying, be sure to check 'Replace destination table (if exists)'.

Comment: I can see it now. I've done as you said and it is working perfectly. For reference for others reading this; ensure you edit the f_table_catalog column to match the name of the new database. Many thanks!